# Elasticsearch count in groups by date range

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have documents like this:

```
{
body: 'some text',
read_date: '2017-12-22T10:19:40.223000'
}
```

Is there a way to query count of documents published in last 10 days group by date? For example:

```
2017-12-22, 150  
2017-12-21, 79  
2017-12-20, 111  
2017-12-19, 27  
2017-12-18, 100
```

Comment: Pro-tip: a number of your Elasticsearch questions here do not seem to feature much in the way of research. This may be a tag in which helpers do not mind offering free labour, but it is worth noting that on Stack Overflow as a whole, prior effort goes a long way. It is appreciated by readers, and may encourage more people to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can easily achieve that using a `date_histogram` aggregation, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "read_date": {
        "gte": "now-10d"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "byday": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "read_date",
        "interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: an error says: failed to parse setting [DateHistogramAggregationBuilder.interval] with value [ day] as a time value

Comment: Sorry, there was a space in there, I removed it, it should work now

Comment: I can't believe this was like a piece of cake!

Answer (score 2):

To receive day count of the past 10 days, per day you can POST the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "read_date": {
        "gte": "now-11d/d",
        "lte": "now-1d/d"
      }
    }
  },

    "aggs" : {
        "byDay" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "read_date",
                "calendar_interval" : "1d",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To the following Url: http://localhost:9200/Index_Name/Index_Type/_search?size=0

Setting size to 0 avoids executing the fetch phase of the search making the request more efficient. See [this elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) for more information.