# Elasticsearch: Find duplicates by field

Tags: elasticsearch

Im working with elasticsearch. I got collection of events, where are event names, for ex. `FC Barcelona - Real Madrit`, then somewhere in collection may be `Footbal Club Barcela - FC Real Madryt`.

I need to find minimum 2 hits without query text. I think aggregation and ngram tokenizer should be used here, but I'm not sure.

Here are my index settings:

```
{
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "test": {
                        "tokenizer": "test",
                        "filter": ["lowercase", "word_delimiter", "nGram", "porter_stem"]
                        "token_chars": [
                            "letter",
                            "digit",
                            "whitespace"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "test": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 15,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And that's how my current query looks like:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eventName",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my mapping:

```
{
            "event": {
                "properties": {
                    "eventName": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        // fielddata: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Could u point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Your mapping and what queries you've tried so far would help us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Tim It has been added to question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the `nGrams` if you are looking for duplicates. You'll want to use the `keyword` type like you have. You can use the terms aggregation like you already have.

```
POST <index_name>/event/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eventName",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The duplicate `eventName` will be listed in the `duplicateEventNames` aggregation buckets. The document `_id` will be in the top `hits` in each bucket.

Comment: Is it possible to filter out items by date? Lets say each event has a eventStart and i want to display only one of these which are starting by same day.

Comment: You probably want to look into a histogram aggregation. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938636/229778). Feel free to ask another question on SO if you're running into issues with it.

Comment: Well this does not work, because it finds results only 1:1, like "FC Barcelona - Real Madrit", won't result with anything if document will have a name like "Football Club Barcelona - Real Madryt"

Comment: @shareone2 - That is a different use case and technically not a duplicate as they are not an exact match. You may want to look into a [More Like This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query instead.